# How to auto fit columns in Finder when in Columns view?

Tags: macos, finder

When in Finder Columns view, how can I automatically resize a column to autofit filenames?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by double-clicking on the border between columns. Note that doing this auto fits the column to the left.

In older versions of macOS (and/or if you have enabled *always show scroll bars* in **System Preferences > General**), you can do it by double-clicking the block below the scroll bar arrows.